# Find existing program path from registry

Tags: inno-setup

How do I find the path of an existing program, so that I can add some more files to one of its directories?

The program has the registry information under:

```
SOFTWARE\GRAPHISOFT SE\ARCHICAD 22\
```

The following code does not work for me:

```
#define PATH ReadReg(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\GRAPHISOFT SE\ARCHICAD 22\") 
DefaultDirName={#PATH}
```